# How to set a user-local python interpreter as default on clusters

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I got access to the server of my lab yesterday. I was trying to do some scientific computing on it with Numpy or so.

The problem is that the server has a SuSE linux(I never heard of such thing..) installed, and it's very difficult to install anything on it. So the administrator suggested that I should set my python environment locally since I did't have root access.

I have checked the default python interpreter on the server, it has python2.6 and python3.x. But I wish to use python2.7.x.

I followed some instructions to install python2.7 into `/home/kevin/.local` with something like this:

```
./configure prefix='/home/kevin/.local'
```

It works, but not easy, because I have to type

```
/home/kevin/.local/bin/python
```

everytime.

So, here is my question: what should I do to set the python2.7 I have installed locally as my default python evironment, so I can use

```
python test.py
```

to run my script. And when I use `pip`, it will install modules locally automatically.

ps: I have went through many of the threads available out there, but they only covers how to install modules locally. So I don't think they meet my purpose. And I also tried `virtualenv`. As I mentioned before, the default python version is 2.6 in `usr/bin/python`, so I can only get a python2.6 virtual environment locally, which is not what I want.

Since English is my second language, I'm not sure whether I have got everything clear. If not, please point out. It would be very kind of you to do so. And thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have python2.7 and virtualenv installed locally, you already have everything you need.

The piece of information you're missing is that you can specify which version of python you want to use when you create your virtualenv. You can use the `-p` option for that.

```
virtualenv -p /home/kevin/.local/bin/python my_virtual_env
```

Once you activate it, your `python` command will refer to the proper installation. Also, if you install via pip, your packages will be installed in `/home/kevin/.local/`

Virtualenv's [documentation](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#usage) can help you better understand if you have more issues.